# How to get some content from xml file by powershell?

Tags: powershell, xml

Variable `$returnedxml` is a sql query result forming in xml. I need to get content 'releasepath'`\\sharespace\test1\\10.0.1212.00`from it

```
<ReleasePath>\\sharespace\test1\\10.0.1212.00</ReleasePath>
```

Here are my code:

```
 $xmldoc= new-object xml.xmldocument

 $xmldoc.load($Returnedxml)

 $xmldoc.releasepath
```

Here are the returned error alarm:

```
Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Could not find file 'C:\Users\admin\System.Xml.XmlDocument'."
At D:\connecttods3andinvoke.ps1:47 char:14
+  $xmldoc.load <<<< ($Returnedxml)
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

I thought xml.xmldocument is a .net class, seems that I was wrong. So what can I do then?

Answer (score 4):

Since the handling of XML data is so integral to so many management tasks, Powershell has an XML Type Accelerator. So this would work as well:

```
[xml]$xmldoc = $returnedxml
$xmldoc.releasepath
```

Comment: According to the error message, it already is an XML document.  So you can skip the first line.

Comment: But look at the file it is trying to find, `'C:\Users\admin\System.Xml.XmlDocument'`.  You can see there is a type name in the string, which is the default ToString() operation.  That tells us that `$Returnedxml` is an XML document, because when converted to a string, you get the type name.  Which is then treated as a relative path, so you get the result `'C:\Users\admin\System.Xml.XmlDocument'`.

Answer (score 2):

I just read it into a string ...

```
$file = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($filename)
```

then use xpath to get values out of it ...

```
$releasePath = $file | SelectXml "//ReleasePath"
```

XPath is really powerful for pulling things out of an XML file, much simpler (coding wise) than using xmldoc

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `$Returnedxml` must be a file name with absolute path. But currently it is an object of class `System.Xml.XmlDocument`.

So change your variable and then you can read the file.

Or on the other hand if you already have an object of XmlDocument in `$Returnedxml` then you do not have to read it into `$xmldoc`. Both are from the same class. Just use $Returnedxml

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong load; that one is for files. Use `LoadXML` instead:

```
$xmldoc.LoadXml($Returnedxml)
```